# What does this indicate in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, indicator

Often I have this screen while doing things on my laptop:
[image]

What is this and what does it indicate? The brightness of the screen automatically dims when this appears and can't be restored to normal, even when there is enough battery remaining. I have to restart my system every time to make it go.

This is my battery settings:

[image]

Comment: That's the monitor brightness indicator. You see it when the system receives a signal (like a keypress) to adjust the brightness level.

Comment: It happens automatically.. I don't press the keys allotted for brightness adjustments. Whenever it appears it is difficult to readjust the brightness. Is it a common problem for 18.04 ?

Comment: No. It could be a hardware fault in your machine. Or it could be a rare bug exposed by the particular combination of your hardware with Ubuntu. Try a 21.04 Live USB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to see if the problem still exists. If a bug, perhaps it's been fixed in the past three years.